# Optimizing postgres contains (LIKE) query in django for CHAR field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I've got a query for a search endpoint in my Django (postgres) backend like so:

```
widgets = Widgets.objects.\
    filter(user=request.user).\
    filter(title__icontains="marketing director").\
    distinct('url')[:250]
```

`title` is a CHAR field (`models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)` in django).

`contains` here of course amounts to a `'%LIKE%'` query in Postgres. I want specifically this (ie: NOT an infix `'LIKE%'` search).

I'd like to speed up that query.

It seems like most optimizations for postgres text search are only for TEXT fields - is there any way to speed up exact string searches on a CHAR column?

I could use Postgres trigram indices, but I don't actually need the fuzzy/mispelling-type search. Though I'd happily use it if it's actually just faster for some reason.

Or would I be better off converting those columns to TEXT, taking the storage increase hit, and better indexing them somehow?

Comment: You should read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations.

Comment: Those are great, but I didn't see a complete performance breakdown, nor what was strictly the fastest.

Comment: You should include some examples of the data you're performing your queries against and what `data['query']` actually may contain. This is because for example the mentioned text search features work on documents of words/lexemes, but you're performing pattern matching against a string currently.

Comment: @IljaEverilä done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* way so use an index with a `LIKE` pattern that starts with `%` (is *not anchored* at the beginning) is to use a trigram index.

It does not matter if you define the attributes as `character` or `text`, since they will be converted to `text` anyway.

Do your data contain a lot of trailing blanks? Other than that, I cannot see how `text` could waste storage space.

Comment: OK, interesting. And no, not very many trailing blanks. What is the performance speed up (generally speaking) for a trigram index over a vanilla LIKE query? Does the speed-up vary linearly with the number of rows added in the database?

Comment: The cost of index access usually grows logarithmically with the number of rows. With a trigram index, you get bad results with short search strings, because they result in a great number of false positive hits. With strings the size of your example it should work fine.

Comment: So in your estimation, a trigram index will be faster than a vanilla LIKE query?

Comment: Yes, unless the search pattern is very short.